# UIWebView unable to select text

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

User unable to select text in some documents loaded into web-view, so "copy, define..." actions doesn't show up.
 What can be a reason to this behaviour?

**Edit:**
For some documents, this same web-view normally select text, so I think the problem is with html-document.

Comment: I want to enable selection, not disable it, it is not duplicate.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, did you get this resolved?

Comment: Same issue on my side. And how can this still be marked as duplicate by 5 different persons when the 2 questions are completely different...?

Answer (score 1):

try check the "User Interaction Enabled" for UIWebView on IB or

```
[webview setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
```

Comment: It is enabled, please, check my edit.

Comment: try override the hitTest:withEvent: method as you can see in post http://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/how-to-pass-touch-events-to-uiwebview/

Comment: can you load html-docement with problem to desktop browser for testing? May be it don't work too.

Comment: I've tried, everething fine.